# Why is my Java program automatically executing if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am currently writing a Java program as a class project (we're allowed notes and SO as a resource) to take an integer systolic and diastolic blood pressure input from a user, and return a corresponding diagnosis ("Your blood pressure is in the range of pre-hypertension", etc.). I am only halfway done with the project, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why this block of code is automatically executing.

Here's the whole code:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    //create method for getting blood pressure and handling exceptions
    private static int getPressure (Scanner l, int num, String pres) {
        //localize variables
        l = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ans;
        //get user input only if it is an integer, otherwise return error message
        //and get user input again
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Please input " + pres + " Blood Pressure:");
                num = l.nextInt();
                break;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, that didn't work. Please ensure your input is a whole number.");
                l.next();
            }
        }
        //Verify user input is as intended, otherwise take input again
        System.out.println("You typed " + num + ", is that correct? (Yes/No)");
        //take input
        ans = l.nextLine();
        //if input does not match one of expected values ("Yes" and "No")
        //return error message and take input again
        do {
            if (Objects.equals(ans, "Yes")) {
                break;
            } else if (Objects.equals(ans, "No")) {
                getPressure(l, num, pres);
            } else if(!(Objects.equals(ans, "Yes") && !(Objects.equals(ans, "No")))) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, invalid input, please type 'Yes' or 'No'");
            }

        } while (true);
        return num;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declare variables
        int sys = 0;
        int dias = 0;
        String systolic = "Systolic";
        String diastolic = "Diastolic";
        Scanner p = new Scanner(System.in);
        getPressure(p, sys, systolic);
        getPressure(p, dias, diastolic);
    }
}
```

and here is the block that is automatically executing for some reason:

```
 else if(!(Objects.equals(ans, "Yes") && !(Objects.equals(ans, "No")))) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, invalid input, please type 'Yes' or 'No'");
            }
```

Here are some sample input/output scenarios with the output unquoted and the input in single quotes:

Expected:

**Please input Systolic Blood Pressure:**

**'120'**

**You typed 120, is that correct? (Yes/No)**

**'Yes'**

**Please input Diastolic Blood Pressure:**

**'90'**

**Process finished with exit code ...**

Actual:

**Please input Systolic Blood Pressure:**

**'120'**

**You typed 120, is that correct? (Yes/No)**

**'Yes'**

**Sorry, invalid input please type 'Yes' or 'No'**

**Please input Diastolic Blood Pressure:**

**'90'**

**Process finished with exit code ...**

Some things I have tried (perhaps foolishly as I truly don't understand certain aspects of Java's Scanner Class"

-Adding l.next(); in various places (just infinitely returns "Sorry, invalid input, please type 'Yes' or 'No'")

-Using ans.equals (same as adding l.next())

-Changing the if/else if/else statements in every way I can imagine (Only produces one of either outcome mentioned here)

Comment: Try adding a System.out.println of ans and ans.length() to see what you are really inputting. Also the last else if() can simply be an else.

Comment: Why are you passing in a scanner as an argument just to create a new scanner? Although this isn't the source of your problem (I have checked) you should not be calling `Object.equals`. You should be calling `equals()` on a String object.

Comment: As noted in the answer below, these scanning from user input problems are notorious.

I would suggest you change your logic so that you only ever "read a line" whenever you want user input. You should then do further processing on that string which you have ready to strip any unwanted characters and convert to the correct type, eg an integer, in some cases.

Comment: You also should absolutly NOT be calling your get function recursively. Every time you enter an invalid value, you are pushing one level deeper into the stack. If you enter 10 wrong values, you have to pop back out of that stack 10 more times. Essentially, the logic doesn't make any sense. This is not a recusion problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this modified code and it works when run with Eclipse on Windows with OpenJDK, Java Version 17.

There were several problems with your code which meant the logic didn't make any sense.

In particular, using a recursive method to get user input which you can't short circuit escape from, makes no sense at all.

Doing things like `inputStream.nextint()` is also a sign of some fragile logic. It is usually better to read a whole line into a string (something that can't really fail) and then process the string to get the input you want.

In this case you want to:

- Strip any whitespace and newlines
- Perform integer conversion with `Integer.valueOf`

Doing it this way will be much more reliable.

I have no idea what `nextInt` does, or under what conditions it works. (eg: does it work if you prepend tabs or spaces? does it work with extra characters following the string? etc...)

There are so many possible combinations of input - the behaviour could be any number of possibilities and only reading the documentation carefully would resolve this.

By the way, the actual reason for your failure (assides from logic errors) was because `nextInt` reads just that - the integer - without the new line character. A new line is left in your input stream, which is then picked up by the next input reading function call.

```
package test;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    
    private static int getPressure(Scanner l, String pres) {

        String ans;
        boolean badUserInput = true;
        Integer num = Integer.valueOf(0);
        
        //get user input only if it is an integer, otherwise return error message
        //and get user input again
        while(badUserInput) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Please input " + pres + " Blood Pressure:");
                ans = l.nextLine();
                ans = ans.strip();
                num = Integer.valueOf(ans);
                badUserInput = false;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, that didn't work. Please ensure your input is a whole number.");
            }
        }
        
        return num.intValue();
    }

    private static boolean checkPressure(Scanner l, int num, String pres) {
        System.out.println("You typed " + num + ", is that correct? (Yes/No)");

        //if input does not match one of expected values ("Yes" and "No")
        //return error message and take input again
        String ans;
        boolean badUserInput = true;
        boolean returnOk = false;
        while(badUserInput ) {
            ans = l.nextLine();
            
            if (ans.equals("Yes")) {
                badUserInput = false;
                returnOk = true;
            } else if (ans.equals("No")) {
                badUserInput = false;
                returnOk = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, invalid input, please type 'Yes' or 'No'");
            }
        }
        
        return returnOk;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int sys = 0;
        int dias = 0;
        String systolic = "Systolic";
        String diastolic = "Diastolic";
        Scanner p = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        boolean repeat = true;
        while(repeat) {
            sys = getPressure(p, systolic);
            boolean returnedValue = checkPressure(p, sys, systolic);
            repeat = !returnedValue;
        }
        
        repeat = true;
        while(repeat) {
            dias = getPressure(p, diastolic);
            boolean returnedValue = checkPressure(p, sys, diastolic);
            repeat = !returnedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I very much appreciate the thorough explanation, I will say the effort is partially lost on me as I just started learning to code a week ago for a self-paced entry level college class. I will keep this block of code as a reference when dealing with efficiency and logic. Do I have your permission to use parts of this code to improve my own work?

Comment: @dharco yes of course feel free to use it for whatever you want. I would suggest do some reading about recursive problems. In short a recursive problem has two key things: a condition for which you call the same function again and a condition for which you exit the function. Stack depth is about how many times you have called that function. A good example is calculating factorials where there is a termination condition resulting from 0! = 1.